# Calculating diagonal points over a distance

Tags: geometry

Bit of an odd question but here goes...

I have got a fence 7m long.  I have got some lights on string that is 10m long.  I want to keep a uniformed look so need to put the lights in a zig zag pattern on the fence.  How do i work out how many points i need across 7m long and the distance between points to keep it uniformed?

Otherwise i would have 3m of lights dangling down at the end of my fence

Does that make sense?!

Comment: It depends on the size of your zigs and your zags! Do you have a preferred or maximum 'zig' and  'zag' (e.g. at most 50cm)? Do you maybe want the zigs and zags to reach the very bottom and top of your fence? If so, what is the height of your fence?

Comment: Can you provide with a crude diagram? Then if you need help with trigonometry someone can post a meaningful answer. Currently, there isn't enough information to effectively answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to create an isosceles single triangle with base `7m` and total length `10m` then you need

[image: L1]

$$ h = \sqrt{ (5)^2 -(3.5)^2 } = 3.57 $$

Now with two triangles

[image: L2]

$$ h = \sqrt{ (2.5)^2 - (1.75)^2 } = 2.38 $$

Or with $n$ triangles

$$ h = \sqrt{ \left( \frac{10}{n+1} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{7}{n+1} \right)^2 } $$

Finally to invert the above, given the fence height $h$

$$ n = \frac{ \sqrt{10^2-7^2}}{h}-1  =\frac{\sqrt{51}}{h}-1 $$

Comment: Thanks thats great! How about with 4 triangles? Which is 1.25m for each length. Is that 1.25 - 0.875 squared?

Unfortunately can't use the height of the fence as its 1m high, so happy to have zig zags in the middle

Comment: You have the equations. Use $n=4$ to get $h$.Just use the Pythagorean theorem to each triangle half.